# pandas groupby sum, count by date time, where consider only year

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a transaction data as shown below. which is a 3 months data.

```
Card_Number Card_type   Category    Amount  Date
0   1       PLATINUM    GROCERY      100    10-Jan-18
1   1       PLATINUM    HOTEL        2000   14-Jan-18
2   1       PLATINUM    GROCERY      500    17-Jan-18
3   1       PLATINUM    GROCERY      300    20-Jan-18
4   1       PLATINUM    RESTRAUNT    400    22-Jan-18
5   1       PLATINUM    HOTEL        500    5-Feb-19
6   1       PLATINUM    GROCERY      400    11-Feb-19
7   1       PLATINUM    RESTRAUNT    600    21-Feb-19
8   1       PLATINUM    GROCERY      800    17-Mar-17
9   1       PLATINUM    GROCERY      200    21-Mar-17
10  2       GOLD        GROCERY      1000   12-Jan-18
11  2       GOLD        HOTEL        3000   14-Jan-18
12  2       GOLD        RESTRAUNT    500    19-Jan-18
13  2       GOLD        GROCERY      300    20-Jan-18
14  2       GOLD        GROCERY      400    25-Jan-18
15  2       GOLD        HOTEL        1500   5-Feb-19
16  2       GOLD        GROCERY      400    11-Feb-19
17  2       GOLD        RESTRAUNT    600    21-Mar-17
18  2       GOLD        GROCERY      200    21-Mar-17
19  2       GOLD        HOTEL        700    25-Mar-17
20  3       SILVER      RESTRAUNT    1000   13-Jan-18
21  3       SILVER      HOTEL        1000   16-Jan-18
22  3       SILVER      GROCERY      500    18-Jan-18
23  3       SILVER      GROCERY      300    23-Jan-18
24  3       SILVER      GROCERY      400    28-Jan-18
25  3       SILVER      HOTEL        500    5-Feb-19
26  3       SILVER      GROCERY      400    11-Feb-19
27  3       SILVER      HOTEL        600    25-Mar-17
28  3       SILVER      GROCERY      200    29-Mar-17
29  3       SILVER      RESTRAUNT    700    30-Mar-17
```

I am struggling to get below dataframe.

```
  Card_No Card_Type  D   2018_Sp  2018_N 2019_Sp 2019_N  2018_Sp   
    1     PLATINUM   70  3300     5      1500    3       1000    
    2     GOLD       72  5200     5      1900    2       1500    
    3     SILVER .   76  2900     5      900     2       1500
```

D = Duration in days from first transaction to last transaction.

2018_Sp = Total spending on year 2018.

2019_Sp = Total spending on 2019.

2017_Sp = Total spending on 2017.

2018_N = Number of transaction in 2018.

2019_N = Number of transaction in 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert to datetimes
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
#sorting if necessary
df = df.sort_values(['Card_Number','Card_type', 'Date'])

#aggregate count and sum 
df1 = (df.groupby(['Card_Number','Card_type', df['Date'].dt.year])['Amount']
       .agg([('Sp','size'),('N','sum')])
       .unstack()
       .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
#MultiIndex to columns
df1.columns = [f'{b}_{a}' for a, b in df1.columns]

#difference (different output, because different years)
s = df.groupby('Card_type').Date.apply(lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()).days).rename('D')

#join together
df1 = df1.join(s).reset_index()
print (df1)
   Card_Number Card_type  2017_N  2017_Sp  2018_N  2018_Sp  2019_N  2019_Sp  \
0            1  PLATINUM    1000        2    3300        5    1500        3   
1            2      GOLD    1500        3    5200        5    1900        2   
2            3    SILVER    1500        3    3200        5     900        2   

     D  
0  706  
1  692  
2  688
```